# Count the subtract in a column between values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column with numerical values. I want to measure how many times the newest price differs from the previous one by 8 points eg...

[image]

```
First I subtract 1 from  2    166-158=8    I  want this to count             
Then  I subtract 2 from  3    158-143=15   I dont want this to count           
Then  I subtract 3 from 4     143-140=3    Neither this     
Then  I subtract 4 from 5     140-132=8    I want his to count
```

So the sql code must return 2 counts

Comment: Please clarify what `by 8 points eg...` means.  Perhaps it means at *most* eight points?  Or at *least* eight points.  But neither example validates this.  What are  the two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*, lag(price) over (order by id) as prev_price
      from t
     ) t
where price = prev_price - 8;
```